# Efficently Loading large amount of data in a fragment

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am making an application that shows a list of my `Custom Model`. Take example of Facebook News feed. My custom model contains `byte arrays` of images. For efficiency I am getting only thumb byte arrays.

Now each listView item contain comments, likes and many other things just like Facebook. I am creating a `custom adapter` in which i am passing `Arraylist` of my custom Model and showing in `ListView`.

Everything is working fine however, i am most concerned about memory issues with android. Since i have thumbs to show and also comments and etc.

My listView is inside a Fragment. How can I show listView items that can contain images, Comments etc, without crashing because of memory or slowing down. Example being Facebook feed page. Or more openly, How can I make something similar to Facebook feed page without getting trouble because of Memory or slowing down issues.

What kind of strategy should I adopt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 - [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) To work with images

2 - Use load more in your listview.

Example:

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));

list.setOnScrollListener(new PauseOnScrollListener(imageLoader, false, true) {

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstItem, int itemsInScreen, int totalItems) {
         super.onScroll(view, firstItem, itemsInScreen, totalItems);

         int lastItemInScreen = firstItem + itemsInScreen;
         if (lastItemInScreen == totalItems) {
             //load more items in your listview
         }
     });
```

Comment: imageloader slows down, tho its not only images i want to scroll, There is a lot of text in the form of comments, etc

Comment: ImageLoader is a fast way to display images. He recycles the views, downloads the images and saved in cache or on disk. This is part of a solution that I have to contribute.

Comment: Another solution is to show you some extra information only when necessary, eg, when you click a list item to see more details (comments for example). Use ArrayAdapter and View Holder Pattern.